# Using percentage in column width resulting in overfull table when getting at 100%

Tags: tables, tabularx, booktabs

I define a columntype which wrap its contens automatically and needs an argument for its width. As I want that my tables are exactly starting at the left margin and ending at the right one I used some kind of percentage from my textwidth.
However, when summing the percentages up to 100 the table gets to wide. It is every time try and error. When having more columns I must land way under 100%, when using less columns the "aim"-value differs. 
Of course I could use tabularx but there were some things not working correct for my issue (to be honest I don't really can remeber what this thing was as it was far in the past).

Mayber there is some workaround that when my column-percentages ends at 1 the table is the excact width of my paper.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe,includeheadfoot, left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array} % Tabellen
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe
 \begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular {C{.10\textwidth}C{.10\textwidth}C{.50\textwidth}C{.30\textwidth}}   % 100% without resizbox
\toprule
Test & Test  &Test & Test \\   \midrule
Test & Test  &Test & Test \\
Test & Test  &Test & Tes       \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
%\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{C{.04\textwidth}C{.04\textwidth}C{.50\textwidth}C{.30\textwidth}}   % 88% without resizebox
\toprule
Test & Test  &Test & Test \\   \midrule
Test & Test  &Test & Test \\
Test & Test  &Test & Tes       \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
%}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{C{.10\textwidth}C{0.10\textwidth}C{.50\textwidth}C{.30\textwidth}}   % 100% with resizebox
\toprule%
Test & Test  &Test & Test \\  \midrule%
Test & Test  &Test & Test \\%
Test & Test  &Test & Tes       \\ \bottomrule%
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This result in this image:

- 1) 100% without resizebox
- 2) 88% without resizebox
- 3) 100% with resizebox

[image: Tables: 1) 100% without resizebox 2) 88% without resizebox 3) 100% with resizebox]

When using resizebox and my value is 100% the font inside is scaled.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a gap of `\tabcolsep` added to both sides of each column, so for 4 columns you need another `8\tabcolsep` of space (unless you put `@{}` between columns}.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe,includeheadfoot, left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array} % Tabellen
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe

\newlength{\freewidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\setlength{\freewidth}{\dimexpr\textwidth-8\tabcolsep}
\begin{tabular}{C{.10\freewidth}C{.10\freewidth}C{.50\freewidth}C{.30\freewidth}}   % 100% without resizbox
\toprule
Test & Test  &Test & Test \\   \midrule
Test & Test  &Test & Test \\
Test & Test  &Test & Tes       \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, don't use `\resizebox` on tables.

For your problem, just remove the `\tabcolsep` space on either side:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe,includeheadfoot, left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array} % Tabellen
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr#1-2\tabcolsep}%
} % zentriert mit Breitenangabe

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{My caption}

\begin{tabular}{
  C{.10\textwidth}
  C{.10\textwidth}
  C{.50\textwidth}
  C{.30\textwidth}
}
\toprule
Test & Test  & Test & Test \\
\midrule
Test & Test  & Test & Test \\
Test & Test  & Test & Tes\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]